# Tips and tricks for finding Scriptures and Grimoires

Tags: warhammer-40k-darktide

Last week and this week my weekly contracts included collecting Grimoires and Scriptures.

[image: Pick up 12 Scriptures]

However the missions which include them seem sparse, so I am keen to try and locate them where possible.

In all the missions that I have played, I have never found one myself. Usually a team mate pings one for me to pickup.

Is there a pattern or style to where they spawn in the missions? Or are they totally random and require investigating every side path, corner and room?

Comment: If these are similar to Grimoires and Tomes in Vermintide, they had set spawn locations on each map, so eventually you'd learn all the spots as you play.  That being said, some of them had some pretty nutty locations... I played the games way after their release so the internet had plenty of resources already...  I also don't remember if there was a "pool" of locations they could spawn, or if they would always be guaranteed to be in the same spots.

Comment: There are a variety of differnet spots for each. Afaik choosen at random at round start.  

As for finding them 
Grimoires glow and make a whispering sound when you are around one.  
Scriptures are usually just off in an odd corner or lonely room is my experience of it. 

Someone also made a webpage to try an catalouge the various spots:
https://manschko.github.io/Darktide-Collectible/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from the comment by @trappski there is a website which shows where to find them

https://manschko.github.io/Darktide-Collectible/

This can show both Grimoires and Scriptures by mission location